# Multiple steps form. All-in-one or multiple web pages

Tags: html, forms

Is it preferable to develop multiple steps form (80+ fields grouped into 5 steps) as single web page (tabbed) compared to page-per-step approach if users tend to complete form when started to populate? 
What are draw-backs big tabbed single page and page-per-step forms usually have?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**IMHO** the division must be done by **relevance on inputs** like an

**Address section** can group all fields like:

```
address 1, ddress 2, zip, country, city, state / province / region
```

while the **Contact section** can group

```
phone number, cell number, work number,  e-mail, myspace, linkedin
```

Then depend, **if all the fields are required or not**!!! you can plan to write it different way!!! for example using tabs!!!

---

**USEFUL TOOLS:**

BTW you can found this links useful

If i could remember right: there are some jQuery Plugin that doing all the job for you by transforming your huge form into step-by-step form!

> - http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx
> - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/babysteps

a must see / try is also this web service

> - http://wufoo.com/

**USEFUL READS:**

> - http://www.deyalexander.com.au/resources/uxd/form-design.html
> - http://www.usability.gov/government/lssnslearned/form.html

Answer (score 2):

Honestly if your form has 80+ fields, I believe you are asking for too much info! No one wants to spend that much time filling in a form. You would have much better success rate with a slimmed down process.

To answer you question though, I think it's more of a personal choice - not really a best practice. I for one prefer one form, tabbed if it has to be. I can scan the page and see all the info you are asking for, decide if I can be bother to complete it and it just seems quicker. I really dislike multipage forms/reg processes. Seems to slow the whole experience down (especially with 5 pages of it).

Perhaps that's just the minimalist in me?

Comment: Ah yes, everybody hates forms. 80+ fields: 20+ required and others are optional. I can't minimize total fields count - there is user background in details, bio, education info, preferences, addresses.
But well, it seems you answer : tabs on one page (instead of multiple pages) are better.

Comment: Indeed they do! Yeah, tabs just make the process a little more bearable. A little more user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If JavaScript is off, what user will see?

If steps are made with usual javascript tabs, then (only if tabs are made with a graceful degradation in mind) user will see one very long form (which isn't so user friendly).

But if it's ajax tabs (based on 5 real pages), then if JS is off user will see 5 links to five pages. Which is better, also, because you can press "back" and refill something you changed your mind about.

Generally, I believe that 5 separate pages, with links "previous" and "next", so user can leave the form not filled up to the end and come back to afterward is a best option. Perhaps some smart ajaxifying could make it somewhat easier, but only with a great thoought behind it.

Comment: Thanks, you remind graceful degradation. I'll take care about that

Comment: **1** - if the OP is going to Use Tabs he can use just CSS; **2** - the point here is not how long should be a form! the form **is** actually long... ! **3** - the step by step form can be done also in plain PHP, js is not needed!

Comment: 1. Please show me cross-browser pure CSS tabs. 

2. The point here is how it's better to implement huge form. Some forms have to be long and there is not much you can do about. Perhaps, when you are looking for a job, you are okay with filling big form that describes your desired position. Also, there are quizzes and other long forms that that's just the way they are.
3. I'm sorry for not making myself clear but my last paragraph meant exactly that: to make five separate pages without use of JavaScript. At least for the basic functionality. Perhaps to enhance the page afterward with JS.

Comment: Please show me cross-browser pure CSS tabs -just the first example that come in mind, enjoy it! ;-)  http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lightbox.html